# Is the quiescent centre only found in monocot roots?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

I read that the quiescent centre is present between the dermatogen and calyptrogen. As calyptrogen is only present in monocot root, does that mean quiescent centre is only found in monocot roots?

Comment: I don't know the answer specifically but unlike the dicot roots the monocots donot show secondary growth in case their roots suffer injuries. So even if the quiescent centre be present in the dicots it makes more relevance in the monocots...

Comment: that's a very valid point, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [quiescent centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiescent_centre) are typically defined by cell division activity not anatomical placement and are not confined to monocots.

For example, this paper discusses the quiescent center in *Arabidopsis* roots<sup>1</sup>.

---

**Reference**:
1: [Doerner, P. (1998). Root development: quiescent center not so mute after all. Current Biology, 8(2), R42-R44.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982298700302)

Comment: Thanks for the article! I found it very informative.

Comment: You're very welcome!